# Podio - PUT via JS client results in empty field

Tags: node.js, podio

I am using the Podio JS NPM module (podio-js) to update fields in my Podio app.  However, I am having a problem where, rather than updating to the new value, the field simply empties... so it basically updates to `null`. Furthermore, despite the fact that some sort of update does in fact take place (albeit the wrong update), the `console.log()`s in the callback are never run - absolutely nothing logs to my console.

Here's the code as I am currently running it:

```
podio.isAuthenticated().then(() => {
    let url = `/item/${podio_item_id}/value/customer-id`
    let requestData = JSON.stringify({data: customer.id})

    podio.request('PUT', url, requestData, (responseData) => {
        console.log("made it")
        console.log(responseData)
    })
})
```

In the docs provided at https://podio.github.io/podio-js/api-requests/, the example `requestData` variable is defined like so:

```
var requestData = { data: true };
```

However, I found that using `{data: customer.id}` in my code did absolutely nothing - I had to `JSON.stringify()` it in order to get this to even come close to working.

In an earlier attempt at accomplishing this, I was able to successfully update Podio via AJAX from my client - the data attribute needed to be formatted like so:

```
data: JSON.stringify({'value': 'true'})
```

I have tried every conceivable iteration of the `requestData` imaginable - stringifying it, stringifying it with additional single quotes (as in my working example), setting it like `{data: {value: customer.id}}`, etc...

Absolutely nothing works - at best, the field simply empties, at worst there is no effect... and no error messages to help my identify the problem.

What is the proper formatting for a `PUT` request to Podio via their JS SDK?

**UPDATE**

On a whim, I thought I'd try using superagent - the following code works perfectly:

```
superagent                  
   .put(`https://api.podio.com/item/${podio_item_id}/value/customer-id`)
   .set('Authorization', `OAuth2 ${accessToken}`)
   .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
   .send(JSON.stringify({'value': `${customer.id}`}))
   .end(function(err, res){
       if (err || !res.ok) {
           console.log(err)
       } else {
           console.log(res)
       }
})
```

I used this exact formatting of the data in my original example as well, same problem as before.

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it - had to format my data like this:

```
let requestData = {'value': `${customer.id}`}
```

**Update**

Also, it is worth noting that the callback function for the `podio.request()` method does not seem to run using the notation described in the documentation. It's a promise, though, so you can treat it as one:

```
podio.request('PUT', `${url}/scustomer-id`, requestData)
.then((response) => {
    //do stuff...
})
```